# Translation of Chinese Scroll and Seal

Tags: translation, seal, calligraphy

Is someone able to help translate the text (calligraphy?) and seal on this scroll?

[image]
[image]

I had a go at translating the seal using [guoxuedashi](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/xz/) and [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/) but wasn't sure how to group the individual elements into characters. Thought the right half might be just 匕玉? Couldn't make any sense of the left half.

Thanks

Comment: 盈懷贈蘭荃 from a poem, [唐 韩愈]《送灵师》, wrote in 戌寅秋, the year 戌寅 could be 1998、1938、1878......, I can't recognize the author name and the seal.

Comment: it should be “戊寅”. there’s no “戌寅” in the sexagenary cycle.

Comment: Sorry - I made a mistake. The second character is 可 and not 石.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The seal pointing to the artist name says 任可澄. In particular, you're very unlikely to find out the last character 「澄」 through a simple search:

- The right hand side of the character 「澄」 in the seal is actually 「⿱豆廾」, which is a [variant shape of 「登」 sometimes appearing in bronze inscriptions](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen?kaiOrder=2716).
- 「澄」 is not a character appearing in bronze inscriptions, so the character in the seal is a modern character *hypothetically back-projected to a bronze inscription form*.